# datatable : load data in chunks

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, angular-datatables

**Requirement :**

I am looking to load a large `dataset` from server into the `jQuery DataTables`.

Instead of loading the entire data on one go, I would like to load the table chunk by chunk. Make an ajax call fetch few hundred rows when the user click on pagination index.

**Example :**

So, in a grid only 10 records per page will be visible and pagination will be upto `50 index`(`10(records per page)*50(pages) = 500(records)`).on click of 50th index we want to fetch another `500 records` and add in the same `datatable` and then index will be upto `100`.

I have a dataset of `1500` records but at one time i am only able to fetch `500` records.

I am exploring various questions in `SO` and also in `datatable forum` but still no solution found so far.

**Datatable Forum :** [Trying to do client side lazy loading](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/23760/trying-to-do-client-side-lazy-loading-using-indexeddb)

Comment: How about using [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)?

Comment: Thanks @Gyrocode.com, it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give a conceptual answer since i don't know anything about your server. Basically on the client you have a `page` variable which initializes to 0. On your server you have a `chunk` variable which is set to 10. Each time you need to load data, you increment `page` and send an ajax request with the `page` as a parameter.

Your server will then query the database for rows `page * chunk` through `(page * chunk)+chunk-1)`. This requires that you select all rows, give each row an index, and then retrieve the proper chunk. Notice the `-1` for [inclusive,exclusive] chunks.

Example:

`page = 0;
chunk start index = page * chunk = 0
chunk end index = page * chunk + chunk - 1 = 9`

Retrieve rows 0-9 from database.

`page = 1;
chunk start index = page * chunk = 10
chunk end index = page * chunk + chunk - 1 = 19`

Retrieve rows 10-19 from database.

`page = 2;
chunk start index = page * chunk = 20
chunk end index = page * chunk + chunk - 1 = 29`

Retrieve rows 20-29 from database.

You can tweek the `chunk` variable to how ever many records you want per call.